# How can I author multiline strings in ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Wondering if it's possible to have multiline string in JSON template? I need to provide powershell script as a part of customscriptextension (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) and so far the only way to do is to have enormously long line. Is it possible instead to have multiline string or how to approach this issue effectively?

Comment: Have you tried it with a multi-line string?  Code editors will balk at it but ARM doesn't care about multi-line strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was added after the question was asked. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax#multi-line-strings for how to use multi-line strings in ARM templates.

Answer (score 0):

you can try and pass this multiline string as base64 encoded and use base64() function to decode it back, but it would probably be easier to just upload the script somewhere and reference it in the extension